# Get deployed contract by address

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

According to [this](https://docs.ethers.org/ethers-app/html/dev-api-contracts.html?highlight=getcontract#connecting-to-a-contract) doc. We can use `ethers.getContract` to get deployed contract.

I have deployed my contract at `0x33F4623337b8F9EDc9529a79F0d68B2BeC98d5E2` and my creator address is `0x6e0F5B57FEdc8911722c92dcD5D7D0cf69ceA385` now to get contract i am doing

```
deployedContract = await ethers.getContract(
                              "0x33F4623337b8F9EDc9529a79F0d68B2BeC98d5E2",
                              "0x6e0F5B57FEdc8911722c92dcD5D7D0cf69ceA385"
                              )
```

But its throwing error

> ```
>  Error: No Contract deployed with name 0x33F4623337b8F9EDc9529a79F0d68B2BeC98d5E2
> ```

But you can see contract is deployed https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x33F4623337b8F9EDc9529a79F0d68B2BeC98d5E2

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just simple.
You can use `getContractAt` function.

```
getContractAt: <T extends ethers.Contract>(
  nameOrAbi: string | any[],
  address: string,
  signer?: ethers.Signer | string
) => Promise<T>;
```

So in your case, it could be:

```
const raffle = await ethers.getcontractAt(
  "Raffle",
  "0x33F4623337b8F9EDc9529a79F0d68B2BeC98d5E2",
  "0x6e0F5B57FEdc8911722c92dcD5D7D0cf69ceA385"
);
```

In addition, you got the error since you used the contract address for the contract name.

```
  getContract: <T extends ethers.Contract>(
    name: string,
    signer?: ethers.Signer | string
  ) => Promise<T>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `0x33F4...` contract is deployed on the Goerli testnet, and it's available only on this network. Your post doesn't state to which network is your ethers `provider` connected to, but based on the context I'm assuming it's a different network - for example the local emulated `hardhat` network (which is the default option if you don't specify any provider) or the Ethereum mainnet.

The `getContract()` function is present only in historic versions of the `ethers` package. Based on the documentation that you linked, it seems that you're using version `0.0.1` (and it seems that it's not a misconfiguration of the docs page, as the 0.0.1 version in fact [exists](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/releases/tag/v0.0.1)). Current version (January 2023) of the package is `5.4` - you can find its docs at https://docs.ethers.io/v5/.

Second argument in the originally linked documentation is `contractInterface`. Which is not the deployer address (passed in your example) but an ABI (Application Binary Interface) - a JSON-formatted specification of `public` and `external` methods of the contract and its events. Example of such ABI JSON can be found in the original docs a below the `Example` headline.

Each contract usually has its own unique ABI that is generated from its source code during contract compilation, but you can also use generic ABI for standardized functions. For example all ERC-20 token contracts have the same functions required by the ERC-20 standard (and these functions are included in the generic ERC-20 ABI), plus they might implement some other functions on top of that (these custom functions are not in the generic ABI).

---

Here's an example of interacting with the contract with the current version (0.5.4) of `ethers`, connected to a Goerli network provider:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
// A 3rd party provider that is connected to the Goerli network
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<your_api_key>");

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x33F4623337b8F9EDc9529a79F0d68B2BeC98d5E2";
// ABI JSON of this specific contract, not included in the answer for readability
const CONTRACT_ABI = [/* ... */];

async function run() {
    const myContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_ABI, provider);
    // `getEntryFee()` function defined in the ABI JSON as well as in the actual contract
    const entryFee = await myContract.getEntryFee();
    console.log(entryFee.toString());
}

run();
```

Note: Above is a standalone NodeJS script that is not using the Hardhat framework. You can also add the network in your Hardhat [config](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#networks-configuration) file, and then run a script from their `scripts` folder that automatically includes `ethers` and connects to the selected provider.

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.17",
    networks: {
        goerli: {
            url: "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<your_api_key>",
            accounts: [<private_key>, <private_key>], // for sending transactions
        }
    }
};
```

```
npx hardhat run --network goerli scripts/myScript.js
```

Comment: got it. I did not realize that I was following older docs

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `hardhat.config.js`

```
networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [process.env.PRI_KEY],
    },
  },
```

create .env and add your env variables

```
// I am loading env variables 
env $(cat .env) npx hardhat run --network goerli scripts/yourScriptFile.js
```